# YUI: how to create a fixedcenter dialog that takes all the vertical space available

Tags: css, dialog, yui

With YUI, I am creating a `fixedcenter` dialog, giving it a certain width:

```
var myDialog = new YAHOO.widget.Dialog("my-dialog", { 
    width : "300px", fixedcenter: true });
```

The content of the dialog is dynamic, and might be large enough that the height of the dialog becomes larger than the height of the viewport. For instance, see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/avernet/svreW/embedded/result/) (to see/change the source click on the "+" at the top right). Make your browser window smaller before loading this example, and you'll see you can't reach the rest of the content in the dialog.

[image: Truncated dialog]

Instead of requiring users to scroll down in the main page to see the rest of the content, I'd like the body of the dialog to expend to the height of the viewport, and when this is not enough, I'd like to have a scrollbar inside the body. This is equivalent to having something like  `.bd { min-height: viewport-height; overflow: scroll }`, where `viewport-height` is the height of the viewport, maybe minus what is necessary for the titlebar.

Setting this `min-height` could be done in JavaScript with code running when the dialog is shown and when the window is resized, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Matt, it would be unfortunate if this can't be done in CSS, but if that is indeed the case, it looks to me like your comment could be an answer (feel free to repost it as such).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...but is there a better way to do this?

Nope - not with CSS.